# SQL Server - Schedule table transfer to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

Can someone advise me on the best way to accomplish the following: transfer all data from around 10 tables - varying from around 200 to 2,000,000 rows - to another server. I've looked into Log Shipping, backing up and restoring the database (although I'm not sure if I can back up specific tables only?). This will need to be done on a daily basis.

Would it be possible/advisable to set them up as Linked Servers, and create a job the selects all data from the source table to the destination tables?

The destination server is only used for reporting purposes, i.e. there is no requirement for it to be a backup for the primary server.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What sql server edition are you on ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Isn't everything there? I need to transfer 10 tables from one server to another, each day. The destination server is only going to be used for reporting purposes, so it doesn't need to be a backup to the primary server. Not sure what else is needed?

Comment: The Question is now closed, but I'd recommend trying `bcp` out and `bcp` in to extract the specific tables.  It might be the least imposition on the source server; however you can also selectively replicate tables.  Replication would essentially solve the problem of having a coherent copy of the 10 tables at all times, but you may prefer your reporting to be based on a known snapshot time.

Answer (score 2):

**Sql Server 2005 - 2008R2**

If you are on Sql 2005 to 2008 R2 edition you have following options to have a reporting server.

1. Replication.
2. Mirroring.
3. Log Shipping.

**Replication**

Will allow you have a live almost Real time data on a separate server to pull your reports. And the replicated server(Report Server to be) is available for reads and writes.

**Mirroring**

Will also give you an almost real time copy of data from Primary Server, Mirror Database(Report Server to be) will always be in a restoring state as log are constantly being restored on the mirror database from the primary database. Therefore database is not available for direct Reads/Writes. You will need to create Snapshots of that mirror database and direct calls from your reporting application to them snapshots.

**Log Shipping**

Will have the secondary database in Standby mode i.e you can read from it but no writes. It will disconnect users when ever logs are restored on it. Or other option is to wait for until no users are connected to the database which may leave you a well out dated data.

**Sql Server 2012-2014**

**Always on Availability groups**

Always on Availability groups . A new feature introduced in Sql server 2012, requires you have Sql Server Cluster and you can have multiple copies of that primary database. Read here for more details [`Overview of AlwaysOn Availability Groups (SQL Server)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff877884.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be your best option, (too many other possible considerations), but you can put all of the tables you want to transfer daily into their own filegroup. Then you can backup / restore that filegroup to transfer the data.

See [MS article on restore of file group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337540.aspx) or [backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189906.aspx) of file group.